# How does heapq push comparison work in 2.7 vs 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, heap

```
import heapq

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

l = [Foo(1)]
heapq.heapify(l)
heapq.heappush(l, Foo(2))
```

This works in Python 2.7 but not in 3.x. As mentioned in the docs

> In the future with Python 3, tuple comparison breaks for (priority, task) pairs if the priorities are equal and the tasks do not have a default comparison order.

How are non-comparable objects handled in 2.7's `heapq.heappush`?

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that you want Foo instances to be compared by their ._x values.  Your code may *run* in 2.x, but it will not *work* in any sensible fashion as Foo instancex will instead be compared by their ids.  Python 3 protects you from such silent bugs by not having a useless default.  heapq at least uses `<`.  The following runs in 3.x and works correctly, at least for this example, in 2.x and 3.x.

```
import heapq

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo(%s)' % self._x
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._x < other._x

l = [Foo(1)]
heapq.heapify(l)
heapq.heappush(l, Foo(2))
print(l)
```

Add other rich comparision methods as needed or desired.  You could add `if isinstance(other, Foo) else NotImplemented` to the end of each `return` expression to make comparisons with non-Foo instances work better.

Comment: So I understand that... I am wondering "How are non-comparable objects handled in 2.7's `heapq.heappush`?" Are the two objects compared by something seemingly random (like their hashes)? Or do they just not sift up the heap when added to the end? Or something else?

Comment: In 2.x, nearly all objects can be 'compared' with the default comparison for CPython being, I believe, by classname and then id.  The idea was that list.sort() should always work, even if the order is arbitrary.  The rule was broken when complex numbers and Guido decided to follow the math conventions that complex numbers are not ordered among themselves, let alone comparable with other things.

Comment: I just tried heapifying a list with two instance of the same class, and the one with the higher id was put in the start of the list. Must be something else, or maybe some function of id.